# Giving each item in my 2d, dynamically sized by user input array an incrementing integer

Tags: c#

My code is supposed to take a user input, use that to determine the size of a 2d array, then turn the items in the array into incrementing integers from 0 onwards eg 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
This is the code I used:

```
    int userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[,] GridArray = new int[userInput, userInput];

        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < GridArray.Length; i++)
        {                    
            if (i == GridArray.GetLength(0))
            {
                k++;
            }
            int gridNumber = i + (k * GridArray.GetLength(0));
            Console.Write(gridNumber + " ");
        }
```

But the output from an input of 4 is like this:
0 1 2 3 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Both a fix for my code
and a method for doing what I am attempting easier would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This code seems to only increment `k` once, because `i` only equals `GridArray.GetLength(0)` once, and you don't increment `k` in the loop definition.  Hence, your inner `for` loop may never end.  Consider refactoring to have the outer `for` loop stop when `i < GridArray.GetLength(0);`and to add `k++;` to your inner loop. (Or else just skip the inner loop entirely, and calculate the 2D array indices from the value of `i`.)

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. How would you suggest I calculate the indices from i. From my understanding .GetLength(0) gives me the length of the row of the array. Is there a similar method to get the length of the whole array.

Comment: You could use two `for` loops inside one another. One loops for `i`, the other for `k`. That way you get all possible combinations.

Comment: On calculating 2D indices from a single incremented value: You would need to use the mod (remainder) operator, `%`.  If your outer index is a 'row' and your inner index a 'column':  `row = i / GridArray.Length(1); col = i % GridArray.Length(1); GridArray[row, col] = i;` Note the integer division for row, which truncates.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, when you enter 4 you would expect to see 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 as the output.

The way you have your nested loops set up, you will always have a never-ending inner loop.  Variable 'k' only increments when 'i' is equal to the length of the zero dimension of your array; which is equal to the userinput.  Which in the first iteration of the outer loop will NEVER occur.  Variable 'i' equals zero for the entire first iteration through the inner loop.

What I believe you will want is to increment each variable within their respective loops.   You will then take the inner loop's index, variable 'k' in your code, and add it to the outer loop's index multipled by the length of the inner loops count.

Try this, I've added the array position in the output for clarity:

```
        int userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[,] GridArray = new int[userInput, userInput];

        for (int i = 0; i < GridArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < GridArray.GetLength(1);k++)
            { 
                int gridNumber = i* GridArray.GetLength(1) + k;
                Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}] = {2}",i,k, gridNumber);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Honestly I wonder why you would want a multi-dimensional array of ordered integers.  If this is just an educational endeavor, that I guess might make sense.  Otherwise the usefulness of this array escapes me.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. It was just an experiment to see if I could.